# ogrinfo says "Unable to open datasource" with KML?

Tags: gdal, ogrinfo

I have [a KMl file](https://pastebin.com/raw/u6hgrecp) that will open fine in QGIS, but when I try to use `ogrinfo` I get:

```
$ ogrinfo -so "myfile.kml" 
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `myfile.kml' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> SDTS
  -> TIGER
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> GMT
  -> GPKG
  -> SQLite
  -> WAsP
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> PCIDSK
  -> OpenFileGDB
  -> XPlane
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> DXF
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
  -> PGDump
  -> OSM
  -> GPSBabel
  -> SUA
  -> OpenAir
  -> PDS
  -> WFS
  -> HTF
  -> AeronavFAA
  -> EDIGEO
  -> GFT
  -> SVG
  -> CouchDB
  -> Idrisi
  -> ARCGEN
  -> SEGUKOOA
  -> SEGY
  -> XLS
  -> ElasticSearch
  -> PDF
  -> CartoDB
  -> SXF
```

Any ideas? I'm working on OSX 10.13,5, if I do `ogrinfo --version` I get `GDAL 1.11.5, released 2016/07/01`.

UPDATE: Here's my KML file https://pastebin.com/raw/u6hgrecp

Comment: what is the debug info? ogrinfo -al --debug on /xxx.kml

Comment: Just says `FAILURE: No datasource specified.`.

Comment: If I do `ogrinfo --formats` the output includes `-> "KML" (read/write)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ogrinfo -so -ro D:\Mapping-GIS-data\test.kml
```

INFO: Open of `D:\Mapping-GIS-data\test.kml'
      using driver`LIBKML' successful.
1: Bolton_Abbey_Estate

It also opens fine in QGIS Desktop

### Maybe upgrade your GDAL 2.3 is out. You're using a very old version.

Comment: confirmed this loaded and converted fine in QGIS 3.0 same GDAL 2.2.3